# Is there a way to pull the "generalError" transactions using the Authorize.net API?

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

Is there a way to pull the "generalError" transactions using the Authorize.net API? I am working on some code to pull all of the ARB (automated recurring billing) subscriptions that have gone bad, in order to email and mail people to ask them to update their information. I can easily get the ones that have expired or card was declined. The problem is that a lot of the ARBs show a status of "Active" but if you go into the ARB history, you see months of "generalError" transactions. I thought maybe I can pull the "generalError" transactions and then look for subscriptionIDs and then I can mark those false "Active" subscriptions as not actually being active. I've been going through every possible way to pull transactions via the API and I can't seem to find a way to pull those "generalError" transactions. They don't appear in settled transactions and don't appear in unsettled transactions. They don't appear in batches because they are not settled. I've also tried pulling all transactions by customerIDs, but those ones always show up as having no transactions for some odd reason.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check *getTransactionListRequest*, for a given batch it returns transaction details, the response includes transactionStatus, and if a given transaction is part of subscription, a subscription block (with id an payNum) will be included.
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/transaction_reporting.html